# Horizontal nav bar with 5 images, CSS

Tags: css

I need a horizontal nav bar with five pre-made images that will serve as links. The images are the same height but not exactly the same width, so I would need to be able to fine tune the horizontal position of each one and spacing between them, I don't want them just lumped together left or right or center.

This is what I have in mind:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OrWh.jpg

How would I go about making this in CSS? I searched and as far as I understand it it's a pretty hard order for a beginner. Multiple horizontal divs? Display:table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #images ul li{
        display: inline;
    }
    #i1{
        background-color:red; 
        margin:20px;
        padding:10;

    }
    #i2{
        background-color:red; 
        margin:20px;
        padding:10;

    }
    #i3{
        background-color:red; 
        margin:20px;
        padding:50;

    }
</style>

<body>

<div id="images">
<ul>
    <li id="i1"> image1</li>
    <li id="i2">image2</li>
    <li id="i3">image3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what i made u can use image instead of text and can set width and height

Answer (score 0):

Use this html:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="page to which image links to"> <img src="img/one.png" alt="" class="image"></a></li>

<li><a href="page to which image links to"> <img src="img/two.png" alt="" class="image"></a></li>

<li><a href="page to which image links to"> <img src="img/three.png" alt="" class="image"></a></li>

<li><a href="page to which image links to"> <img src="img/four.png" alt="" class="image"></a></li>

<li><a href="page to which image links to"> <img src="img/five.png" alt="" class="image"></a></li>
```

Then put put this into CSS:

```
nav ul{list-style: none;}
```

You will get rid of the bullet points.